# How to search in foursquare api using more than id

Tags: php, api, foursquare

I was integrate foursquare api with my website.I want to search in foursquare by sending array of ids to api and retrive data of each id  .
What i found searching using only id like that
https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/venues I want to search with array of ids

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to plug in a list of venue ID's to the API and get back responses, and using the venue details call you linked to is the only way. However, using a [multi](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/multi/multi) request could help reduce the number of calls?